# Ajax function sends GET request but PHP never process it

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax to run a function in a PHP script. My two script files are as follows:

get.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "testPhp.php",
    data: { param1: "INITIALIZE"},
    type: "GET",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() {
    alert("DONE!");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

testPhp.php:

```
<?php
    define("SERVER_NAME", "localhost");
    define("USERNAME", "root");
    define("PASSWORD", "");
    define("DATABASE", "myDB");

    //Print database info
    echo nl2br("Server Name: " . SERVER_NAME . "\nUsername: " . USERNAME .     "\nPassword: " . PASSWORD);

    //Connecting to database
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    //Check database connection
    if($mysqli === false) {
        die ("\nCould not connect:  " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        echo nl2br("\nConnected successfully! Host info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli));
    }

    //Function to execute database queries
    function executeQuery($sql_query, $mysqli) {
        if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_query)){
            echo nl2br("\n\nQuery executed successfully: $sql_query");
        } else {
            echo nl2br("\n\nERROR: Could not able to execute $sql_query. " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
        }
   }

    function initializeDatabase() {
        //Query to create flashcards database
        $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . DATABASE;
        executeQuery($sql, $mysqli);
   }

   if(isset($_GET["param1"])) {
        $arg = $_GET["param1"];
        if($arg == "INITIALIZE") {
            initializeDatabase();
        }
    }
```

testPhp.php contains other methods, but none are called yet. When I run the PHP script with the code of `initializeDatabase()` outside of the function, so it will automatically run, it works perfectly. The `alert()` also occurs a couple seconds after I load my webpage, when the script is run, so it seems like it is doing something during the run of the function before exiting. However, when I use the Ajax GET request, it seems as if PHP is not responding. Any ideas?

Comment: Console errors? Add error handling to the Ajax too

Comment: @mplungjan I don't see any errors when it is run.

Comment: `$.ajax({
    url: "testPhp.php",
    data: { param1: "INITIALIZE"},
    type: "GET",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() {
    alert("DONE!");
}).fail(function(){ console.log(arguments);});` look if fail function is called and figure out your failure in the php script

Comment: @mtizziani I added your code and no errors are reported. The only thing that happens is the alert when the function is finished

Comment: i think i found the failure. looks like you run initalizeDatabase function before you build up the connection. set it to the end and its possible to run as quick fix

Comment: @mtizziani I tried your suggestion, but it still will not work

Comment: Start by checking what your script actually receives - put `var_dump($_GET); exit;` at the beginning of the script, and check the output in the browser dev tools network panel.

Comment: @CBroe I tried that and there is no output to the console

Comment: So does it work when you call it directly via the browser address bar, and not AJAX?

Comment: How exactly do you know it isn't working? If you're getting `DONE!` then it is working to some extent.

Comment: @KevinB i think he is wondering why he did not get more information. but if you do not more than an alert, you won't get more.

Answer (score -1):

It could be failing because in the function `initializeDatabase()`, `$mysqli` is an undefined variable. Try passing `$mysqli` to `initializeDatabase()`.

Comment: Just tried that, but unfortunately it didn't correct the issue